# error in confusion matrix the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Tags: r

I've trained an SVM model. I'm now trying to generate a confusion matrix and keep getting the following error:

> Error in confusionMatrix.default(test.pred,
>   data_test$FAVOURITES_COUNT) :    the data cannot have more levels than
>   the reference

Here is the code

```
model <- svm(FAVOURITES_COUNT~., data = data_train);

test.pred <- predict(model, data_test,na.action = na.pass);

confusionMatrix(test.pred,data_test$FAVOURITES_COUNT)
```

I have tested if they have same levels using:

```
> identical (levels(test.pred), levels(data_test$FAVOURITES_COUNT))
[1] TRUE
```

structure of both `pred` and `data_test$FAVOURITES_COUNT`:

```
>  str(test.pred)  Named num [1:440] 1539 1516 1560 1560 1450 ...
>  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:440] "1" "4" "11" "13" ...

> str(data_test$FAVOURITES_COUNT)
 int [1:440] 62 10725 84 84 19 99 54 84 84 84 ...
```

I think the problem is related to chr and int different types but I don't know how to solve this , there is already another question like this but it doesn't provide a solution also if I change the chr to int

```
pred<-as.integer(format(round(predict(model,data_test))))
```

the problem is still there. How can I resolve this error

Dataset

[data](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=e32b61b756876ffa8e5926811820cfdef2c92d14405606ef3fbcf1fdeaae0b619727171e8d6a42530234dde72d427b2297382d024282dadbe3197ac15b68f139)

complete code

```
rm(list=ls())
df <- read.csv("path/data.csv")
mydata <- df
mydata$ALTMETRIC_ID <- NULL


#library(caret)
split=0.60
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- mydata[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- mydata[-trainIndex,]
#library(e1071)

model <- svm(FAVOURITES_COUNT~., data = data_train);

test.pred <- predict(model, data_test,na.action = na.pass);

confusionMatrix(test.pred,data_test$FAVOURITES_COUNT)
```

Comment: It is always better to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus added

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue because the algorithm was predicting results only for one outcome, we need to make sure that our testset has enough of both the outcomes classes such as N and O in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue. You need to convert the dependent variable column favorites_counts to factor before creating the train and test.IE.

```
mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT<-factor(mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT)
```